# Match array values with array values in multi-dimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I have 2 arrays:

1. `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`
2. `[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]`

Is there a way I can find the number of sub-array in the second array which contains the values of the first array using Python?

For the above, it would be `2`

Comment: @AlexandreAlencar no just the presence of even a single element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
s = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
final_val = len([i for i in a if any(b in s for b in i)])
```

Output:

```
2
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, for each element in the first array, you must check if it is in the sub-arrays of the second.
However, this is quite inefficient, so you can proceed like this:

For each sub array in second, check it it contains any element of First, if it is the case, add one to the count, and check the next sub array.

```
first = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
second = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

matches = 0
for sub in second:
    for elt in sub:
        if elt in first:
            matches += 1
            break

print(matches)
```